# Find probability of classification of observations to one of two possible normal distributions

Tags: probability, classification, normal-distribution

Imagine you start with two relatively large samples of sample sizes 15 and 18 respectively. We can assume they each come from a different normal distribution.

The first (15 observations) comes from distribution A and has a mean 10 and a standard deviation of 3

The second (18 observations) comes from distribution B has a mean 15 and a standard deviation of 3.5

(to be clear, the mean and standard deviations listed above are of observations, not the distributions themselves)

Then you are given a third and a fourth sample (sample C and sample D) of 3 observations each: let's say {12, 11, 8} and {14, 16, 13}
You know that each new sample comes from one of the two distributions and that they both come from different distributions. How do you determine the probability that the sample C comes from distribution A and sample D comes from distribution B and vice versa?

Tries so far: I have written a bootstrapping program that simulates the scenario mentioned 100,000 times, but I would prefer an analytical solution. I have tried using the negative log likelihood of a T distribution similar to the solution mentioned below, but the answers I have gotten are substantially different than what I get in my program.

Comment: This sounds like a homework question. What is the exact phrasing? The idea that immediately came to mind does not answer the question as you’ve phrased it but does answer a related question. Also, please add the self-study tag, read its wiki, and edit your question to include what you’ve done so far.

Comment: @dave It's not a homework question. The topic came up organically in some data analysis I'm working on. I wrote the question like this because the actual problem I'm trying to solve is a bit more convoluted, and I wanted to reduce it to its most basic parts.

Comment: Distribution A and B are assumed to have potentially different variance?

Comment: Yes, the observation is that they have different standard deviations

Comment: If the moments of the two normal distributions are known then the initial data is irrelevant --- the problem is solved by a simple application of Bayes' theorem.  Are you sure you intend for the initial data to be irrelevant?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. The only thing I know about the true distributions is what I have observed from the samples I took. I don't know the true mean or standard deviation of the distributions. I only have the mean and standard deviation of the data.

Answer (score 1):

One way would be using log likelihood, so the sum of log likelihoods of each unit, in this case obtained from a normal distribution. Computation in R

```
> -sum(dnorm(c(12,11,8),10,3,log=T))
[1] 6.552652
> -sum(dnorm(c(12,11,8),15,3.5,log=T))
[1] 9.535513
```

The goal is to minimize this value so the first case with mean 10 and SD of 3 is a better fit for the new data.

Comment: I like the approach, but if I understand correctly, this method does not account for the uncertainty of the mean and standard deviation of the original two samples

Comment: @JeremyDorner Regarding your edit, the mean and SD are unbiased estimators for the case of normal distributions, so they are your best "guesses" for the population.

Comment: I see. I was looking for the probability that each classification is correct, rather than the most likely classification.

Comment: @JeremyDorner Rough estimate `1-(6.552652/(6.552652+9.535513))` to get the probability of belonging in the first population.

Comment: Ah I got your point. Yeah that correctly answers the question as I asked, but would it still be valid if sample A and sample B have different sample sizes? I am not sure. I have updated the question to reflect this. My bad for not including it originally.